# AMP Test Shows No Errors by GSC says So

Tags: console, amp-html

Here are the two pages that the Google Search Console shows 2 Critical Errors for:
1. https://www.hillwebcreations.com/fix-product-markup-errors-avoid-google-manual-action/amp/
2. https://www.hillwebcreations.com/google-image-guidelines/amp/

Both (out of 80+ post are the only two with issues all use the exact same AMPforWP plugin) show the same 2 issues:

Details:

(1) The mandatory tag 'amphtml engine v0.js script' is missing or incorrect.
(2) The mandatory tag 'link rel=canonical' is missing or incorrect.

But then when I run the link to the AMP TEST, both say "Valid AMP page
Page is eligible for AMP search features in Google search results".

https://search.google.com/test/amp?utm_source=wmx&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=wmx-agg&id=KWGeOzUCXJ7fBP9azfDLIw

https://search.google.com/test/amp?utm_source=wmx&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=wmx-agg&id=Josb4P-x6poP3B_96qRJhw

And oddly, the one URL has a strange "v" added to the end. Where does that come from?

https://www.hillwebcreations.com/fix-product-markup-errors-avoid-google-manual-action/amp/v/

Thanks in advance for any help to sort this out.

Comment: The Search Console suggests:
"Run the AMP Test to verify and fix your AMP markup... The test will show all AMP errors on the page, ***including this error*** type and any others that it finds in the live version of the page." 

After running it, no errors exist "including this error type" nor any others.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/issues/411) regarding your issue `The mandatory tag '%1' is missing or incorrect.` It might be a conflict with another plugin that's modifying the output of AMP pages. Best option is to disable it for any URLs that end in `/amp/?`. Based from this [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/validation_errors), the fix is to add (or correct) the mandatory HTML tag.

Comment: Thank you for your insights Abielita. The Search Console says: 

How have you successfully corrected a similar mandatory HTML tag when using the AMPforWP plugin? 

One page includes an iframe embedded Google Hangout . Perhaps that is what triggers the issue on this page.

Comment: Dev Vercer, thanks for your response. 

Doesn't using the Fetch as Google tool refresh that? I have done so, yet the error messages remain. When tested all pages still show up with perfect scores.

This looks like it would take more hours to determine what these instructions mean that is possible given my current schedule. Might you or someone you know, who already has the needed experience, be for hire?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Google Search Console has a different copy of your web page than the AMP Test tool. Google Search Console doesn't fetch your page live, it is using Google's last crawled version. It is possible that the page has changed since then and this issue will resolve itself after some crawling time has passed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Gregable. We have read this AMPHTML validation troubleshooting page for some time. It is a helpful reference; its another matter to fully understand and apply everything on it.

Rather than resolving with time, a new critical error appears: 

Only AMP runtime 'script' tags are allowed, and only in the document head.
https://www.hillwebcreations.com/solving-e-commerce-website-seo-technical-issues/amp/

One possibility: An update for the Contact Form 7 for AMP just showed up today; perhaps that triggered/resolves it.

Comment: Another possibility is that you are using a CDN which sometimes inserts javascript into your pages on a fraction of requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the version that Google has cached in the amp-cache by using the update-ping url (include the full path to the page after the domain):

https://cdn.ampproject.org/update-ping/c/s/example.com/

See details here: https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache